# codeigniter database error while upload to cpanel

Tags: database, codeigniter, upload

I am trying to upload my codeigniter website to cpanel
But, I am getting following error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: core/Loader.php
Line Number: 346
```

I have uploaded all my files in directory:
/home/mycpanelusername/public_html/

And,

```
database name = mycpanelusername_db_databasename
databae username = mycpanelusername_fajs
database password = mydbpassword
```

and I granted all privileges to my database

My database.php file is like this:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'http://myurl.org';
$db['default']['username'] = 'mycpanelusername_fajs';
$db['default']['password'] = 'mydbpassword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mycpanelusername_db_databasename';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Thank you, If it's not clear please ask me

Answer (score 1):

give $db['default']['hostname'] as ip address

```
$db['default']['hostname'] ="254.000.0.0";
```

or

`$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';`

try like this

Answer (score 0):

Try with localhost like

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
```

May it works and also once check the login credntionals and Db name

Comment: Glad it helps for you,Now You can accpet it